# how to add multiple argument options in python using argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

**My Requirement:**

For now when I run my python application with this command

```
python main.py -d listhere/users.txt
```

The program will run and save the result file as predefined name say ***reports.txt***

Now I want to add this functionality to allow users to choose what to put the filename and where to save as so

```
python main.py -d -o output/newfilname -i listhere/users.txt
```

Everything is same but I want another argument -o to be passed which will determine the filpath and name to be saved. How do I do it. What is the best way to handle or combine multiple options.

**I tried this**

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "CHECK-ACCESS REPORTING.")
    parser.add_argument('--user','-d', nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument('--output','-d -o', nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument('--input','-i', nargs='?')
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

   if args.output and args.input:
        #operation that involves output filename too
   elif args.user and not args.input:
       #default operation only
   else:
      #notset
```

I am getting this error when trying to solve the issue this way

**Error:**

**report.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -o listhere/users.txt**

Comment: You can't attach more `-` options to another `-` option, no, `-d -o` is not a valid option name here. Why not just have a `-o` option to specify the output name?

Comment: remove -d and it will work

Comment: Why I did that is if I don't pass some values after -d it wont work . How to make -d as just the parameter without value. Tried appending default='' to -d  but not working

Comment: if i print the value of arg with this parameter i get nothing 
`python report.py -d -o listhere/users.txt -i list/here.txt`

Comment: What's the difference between the old `-d users.txt` and the new `-i users.txt`? What's the purpose of option `-d`?

Comment: if `-d` only comes the app will use default name and file location to save the report and also d indicates its a discrepancy report. and if `-o` comes the new path and nave given by users will be used instead and `-i` is the input path that we directly passed in default case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `nargs='?'` flagged option works in 3 ways

```
parser.add_argument('-d', nargs='?', default='DEF', const='CONST')
```

commandline:

```
foo.py -d value # => args.d == 'value'
foo.py -d       # => args.d == 'CONST'
foo.py          # => args.d == 'DEF'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#const

Taking advantage of that, you shouldn't need anything like this erroneous `-d -o` flag.

If you don't use the `const` parameter, don't use '?'

```
parser.add_argument('--user','-u', nargs='?', const='CONST', default='default_user')
parser.add_argument('--output','-o', default='default_outfile')
parser.add_argument('--input','-i', default='default_infile')
```

Comment: Thanks very descriptive I was very much unclear about default ,const

Comment: Another thought: `-d -o` is split into 2 strings by the `bash`; sometimes it helps to look at `sys.argv` to seek what `argparse` has to work with.

Comment: can you consider this please `python testing.py -d  -i somevalue -o somevalue`  I dont want to pass value after -d which result in not satisfying the condition `if args.users:
                                           if args.input and args.output`

Comment: Ok did it by setting the const="some value"

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have something like this:

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Check-Access Reporting.',
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-d',
        dest='discrepancy',
        action='store_true',
        help='Generate discrepancy report.',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input',
        '-i',
        default='users.txt',
        help='Input file for the report.',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output',
        '-o',
        default='reports.txt',
        help='Output file for the report.',
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.discrepancy:
        print('Report type: {}'.format(args.report_type))
        print('Input file: {}'.format(args.input))
        print('Output file: {}'.format(args.output))
    else:
        print('Report type is not specified.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result of option `--help`:

```
usage: ptest_047.py [-h] [-d] [--input INPUT] [--output OUTPUT]

Check-Access Reporting.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d                    generate discrepancy report (default: False)
  --input INPUT, -i INPUT
                        input file for the report (default: users.txt)
  --output OUTPUT, -o OUTPUT
                        output file for the report (default: reports.txt)
```

Without any option (or missing option `-d`):

```
Report type is not specified.
```

With option `-d`:

```
Report type: discrepancy
Input file: users.txt
Output file: reports.txt
```

With `-d --input input.txt --output output.txt`:

```
Report type: discrepancy
Input file: input.txt
Output file: output.txt
```

Comment: The problem there is you have to pass some value after -d flags I just want to pass the flag -d without any value to it

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung The order of the options does not matter, e.g.: -o output.txt -i input.txt -d. Option -d does not have any value on the command line. If the option is used somewhere on the command line, then it sets variable `discrepancy` to true.