# Argparse optional argument with different default if specified without a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Consider three different runs of a program:

```
python3 prog.py
python3 prog.py --x
python3 prog.py --x 2
```

Is it possible to use `argparse` such that, for example, in the first case, `x==None`, in the second case, `x==1`, and in the third, `x==2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nargs'?'` with a `const` parameter handles this 3-way input nicely..

```
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: parser.add_argument('-x','--x', nargs='?', type=int, const=1)
...
In [4]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[4]: Namespace(x=None)
In [5]: parser.parse_args(['-x'])
Out[5]: Namespace(x=1)
In [6]: parser.parse_args(['-x','2'])
Out[6]: Namespace(x=2)
```

I could have also given it a `default` parameter.

[how to add multiple argument options in python using argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745588/how-to-add-multiple-argument-options-in-python-using-argparse)

Comment: +1  I did not know about this usage of `const`.  I'd give away the check-mark if I could, hopefully OP will see this and change their accepted answer.

Comment: This `nargs='?'` combined with `const` is brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider instead the [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) action, which is commonly used to specify verbosity levels. The usage is different, for example:

```
python3 prog.py
python3 prog.py -v
python3 prog.py -vv
```