# Optional named arguments with argparse

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

It's valid to use my Python program in any of these 3 ways:

```
$ python prog.py # 1
$ python prog.py -d # 2
$ python prog.py -d FILE # 3
```

Each of these do different things. (1) does not dump stuff to a file at all. (2) dumps it to `dump.log`. (3) dumps it to `FILE`.

I'm unsure how to distinguish between (1) and (2) after I've called `parse_args()`. Here is my code:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-t', '--tag-dump',
    metavar='FILE',
    help="dump enriched tags to FILE (default: dump.log)",
    action='store',
    nargs='?',
    dest='etags_filename',
    default='dump.log'
)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

What do I do now?

Comment: Define a `const` parameter as well.

Comment: Have you tried running this? The fact that you have `-t`  the hyphen before the flag indicates that it is optional.

Comment: Your sample command line uses `-d` but your code snippet defines `-t` and not `-d`. Which is it?

Comment: See [Argparse optional argument with different default if specified without a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412407/argparse-optional-argument-with-different-default-if-specified-without-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide a [`const`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#const) argument to `parser.add_argument()`. This specifies the value that will be filled in if the option is used without specifying a value on the command line. You can then test whether `args.etags_filename` is the `const` value (case 2) or the `default` value `'dump.log'` (case 1).